# How to do Handoff implementation with QnA Bot using Asp.net Core

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, botframework

I have implemented a QnA functionality but unable to implement a Bot handoff to humans. Here is the scenario,

If a user wants to connect to an agent because he is not satisfied with the bot answers request will be delegated to Bot.

here is the QNA maker code. could anyone suggest this?

// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using NCIBot;
using NCIBot.Bots;
using NCIBot.CommandHandling;
using NCIBot.ConversationHistory;
using NCIBot.MessageRouting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Underscore.Bot.MessageRouting;
using Underscore.Bot.MessageRouting.DataStore;
using Underscore.Bot.MessageRouting.DataStore.Azure;
using Underscore.Bot.MessageRouting.DataStore.Local;
using Underscore.Bot.MessageRouting.Results;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots
{
    public class QnABot<T> : ActivityHandler where T : Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Dialog
    {
        protected readonly BotState ConversationState;
        protected readonly Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Dialog Dialog;
        protected readonly BotState UserState;
        protected readonly CosmosTranscriptStore TranscriptStore;
        private const string KeyRejectConnectionRequestIfNoAggregationChannel = "RejectConnectionRequestIfNoAggregationChannel";
        private const string KeyPermittedAggregationChannels = "PermittedAggregationChannels";
        private const string KeyNoDirectConversationsWithChannels = "NoDirectConversationsWithChannels";


        public IConfiguration Configuration
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }

        public MessageRouter MessageRouter
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }

        public MessageRouterResultHandler MessageRouterResultHandler
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }
        public CommandHandler CommandHandler
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }
        public MessageLogs MessageLogs
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }

        public QnABot(ConversationState conversationState, UserState userState, T dialog, CosmosTranscriptStore transcriptStore, IConfiguration config)
        {
            ConversationState = conversationState;
            UserState = userState;
            Dialog = dialog;
            TranscriptStore = transcriptStore;
            string connectionString = ""; // Configuration[KeyAzureTableStorageConnectionString];
            Configuration = config;
            IRoutingDataStore routingDataStore = null;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"WARNING!!! No connection string found - using {nameof(InMemoryRoutingDataStore)}");
                routingDataStore = new InMemoryRoutingDataStore();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Found a connection string - using {nameof(AzureTableRoutingDataStore)}");
                routingDataStore = new AzureTableRoutingDataStore(connectionString);
            }

            MessageRouter = new MessageRouter(
                routingDataStore,
                new MicrosoftAppCredentials(Configuration["MicrosoftAppId"], Configuration["MicrosoftAppPassword"]));

            //MessageRouter.Logger = new Logging.AggregationChannelLogger(MessageRouter);
            ConnectionRequestHandler connectionRequestHandler =
               new ConnectionRequestHandler(GetChannelList(KeyNoDirectConversationsWithChannels));
            MessageRouterResultHandler = new MessageRouterResultHandler(MessageRouter);

            CommandHandler = new CommandHandler(
                MessageRouter,
                MessageRouterResultHandler,
                connectionRequestHandler,
                GetChannelList(KeyPermittedAggregationChannels));
            //MessageRouterResultHandler = new MessageRouterResultHandler(MessageRouter);

            MessageLogs = new MessageLogs(connectionString);
        }
        private IList<string> GetChannelList(string key)
        {
            IList<string> channelList = null;

            string channels = Configuration[key];

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(channels))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Channels by key \"{key}\": {channels}");
                string[] channelArray = channels.Split(',');

                if (channelArray.Length > 0)
                {
                    channelList = new List<string>();

                    foreach (string channel in channelArray)
                    {
                        channelList.Add(channel.Trim());
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"No channels defined by key \"{key}\" in app settings");
            }

            return channelList;
        }
        public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            
            await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
            if (turnContext.Activity.Text!=null && (turnContext.Activity.Text.Contains("watch", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || turnContext.Activity.Text.Contains("unwatch", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
                if (turnContext.Activity.Text.Equals("watch", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Command command = new Command(Commands.Watch, null, null);
                    Activity activity = turnContext.Activity;
                   await CommandHandler.TakeAgentAction(turnContext, activity, command);
                }
                if (turnContext.Activity.Text.Equals("unwatch", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    Command command = new Command(Commands.Unwatch, null, null);
                    Activity activity = turnContext.Activity;
                    await CommandHandler.TakeAgentAction(turnContext, activity, command);
                }
            }
            await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
            await UserState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        }
        protected virtual Task OnHandoffActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IHandoffActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        //protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        //{
        //    //turnContext.Activity.Text = MaskData(turnContext.Activity.Text);
        //    await TranscriptStore.LogActivityAsync(turnContext.Activity);

        //    // Get the state properties from the turn context.
        //    MessageRouter.StoreConversationReferences(turnContext.Activity);
        //    AbstractMessageRouterResult messageRouterResult = null;

        //    bool.TryParse(
        //            Configuration[KeyRejectConnectionRequestIfNoAggregationChannel],
        //            out bool rejectConnectionRequestIfNoAggregationChannel);

        //    var conversationStateAccessors = ConversationState.CreateProperty<ConversationData>(nameof(ConversationData));
        //    var conversationData = await conversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ConversationData());

        //    var userStateAccessors = UserState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
        //    var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());

        //    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userProfile.Id))
        //    {
        //        // First time around this is set to false, so we will prompt user for name.
        //        if (conversationData.PromptedUserForId)
        //        {
        //            // User userdetails = AuthenticateUser(turnContext.Activity.Text?.Trim());

        //            // if (userdetails != null)
        //            // {
        //            //    userProfile.Id = userdetails.Id;
        //            //    userProfile.Name = userdetails.firstName + " " + userdetails.lastName;
        //            //var thanksMsg = $"Thank you and welcome {userProfile.Name}.";

        //            userProfile.Id = turnContext.Activity.Text?.Trim();
        //            var thanksMsg = $"Thank you";
        //            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(thanksMsg);

        //            IActivity activityFromBot = BuildActivity(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Bot", turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id, thanksMsg);
        //            await TranscriptStore.LogActivityAsync(activityFromBot);

        //            turnContext.Activity.Text = "Hello";
        //            // Reset the flag to allow the bot to go through the cycle again.
        //            conversationData.PromptedUserForId = false;
        //            //}
        //            /*else
        //            {
        //                var invalidUserIdMsg = $"Your account validation is failed with given UserId";
        //                IActivity activityFromBot = BuildActivity(turnContext.Activity.Id, "Bot", turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id, invalidUserIdMsg);

        //                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activityFromBot);
        //                await TranscriptStore.LogActivityAsync(activityFromBot);

        //                conversationData.PromptedUserForId = false;
        //                await PromptForUserId(turnContext);
        //                return;
        //            } */
        //        }
        //        else
        //        {
        //            await PromptForUserId(turnContext);
        //            // Set the flag to true, so we don't prompt in the next turn.
        //            conversationData.PromptedUserForId = true;
        //            return;
        //        }
        //    }
        //    else if (turnContext.Activity.Text.Equals("Save Transcript", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        //    {
        //        StringBuilder transcriptContents = await GetTranscriptContents(turnContext, userProfile);

        //        byte[] bytes = StringToBytes(transcriptContents.ToString());

        //        var contentType = "text/plain";
        //        var attachment = new Attachment
        //        {
        //            Name = $"Transcript_{userProfile.Name}.txt",
        //            ContentUrl = $"data:{contentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)}",
        //            ContentType = contentType
        //        };

        //        var activity = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachment);
        //        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity);

        //        //turnContext.Activity.Text = MaskData(turnContext.Activity.Text);
        //        // await TranscriptStore.LogActivityAsync(turnContext.Activity);
        //        return;
        //    }
           
        //    else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(turnContext.Activity.Text)
        //                    && (turnContext.Activity.Text.ToLower().Contains("human") || turnContext.Activity.Text.ToLower().Contains("agent")))
        //    {
        //        // Let the message router route the activity, if the sender is connected with another user/bot
        //        messageRouterResult = await MessageRouter.RouteMessageIfSenderIsConnectedAsync(turnContext.Activity);

        //        if (messageRouterResult is MessageRoutingResult
        //               && (messageRouterResult as MessageRoutingResult).Type == MessageRoutingResultType.NoActionTaken)
        //        {
        //            // Create a connection request on behalf of the sender
        //            // Note that the returned result must be handled
        //            //var transcriptContent = await GetTranscriptContents(turnContext, userProfile);
        //            //turnContext.Activity.Text = transcriptContent.ToString();
        //            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"You have requested transfer to an agent, ConversationId={turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id}");
        //            IActivity activity = turnContext.Activity;

        //            //messageRouterResult = MessageRouter.CreateConnectionRequest(
        //            //MessageRouter.CreateSenderConversationReference(turnContext.Activity, rejectConnectionRequestIfNoAggregationChannel));
        //            //messageRouterResult = MessageRouter.CreateConnectionRequest(
        //            //       MessageRouter.CreateSenderConversationReference(activity),
        //            //       rejectConnectionRequestIfNoAggregationChannel);


        //            if (activity.Type is ActivityTypes.Message)
        //            {

        //                if (await CommandHandler.HandleCommandAsync(turnContext) == false)
        //                {
        //                    // No command detected/handled

        //                    // Let the message router route the activity, if the sender is connected with
        //                    // another user/bot

        //                    messageRouterResult = MessageRouter.CreateConnectionRequest(
        //                 MessageRouter.CreateSenderConversationReference(activity),
        //                 rejectConnectionRequestIfNoAggregationChannel);
        //                }
        //            }
        //            else
        //            {
        //                // No action taken - this middleware did not consume the activity so let it propagate
        //               // await next(ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
        //            }




        //        }
        //        // Handle the result, if necessary
        //        await MessageRouterResultHandler.HandleResultAsync(messageRouterResult);
        //        return;
        //    }

        //    // Add message details to the conversation data.
        //    // Convert saved Timestamp to local DateTimeOffset, then to string for display.
        //    var messageTimeOffset = (DateTimeOffset)turnContext.Activity.Timestamp;
        //    var localMessageTime = messageTimeOffset.ToLocalTime();
        //    conversationData.Timestamp = localMessageTime.ToString();
        //    conversationData.ChannelId = turnContext.Activity.ChannelId.ToString();

        //    // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
        //    await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        //    var dialodAccesser = ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState));
        //    var dialog = await dialodAccesser.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new DialogState());
        //    var _dialogSet = new DialogSet(dialodAccesser);
        //    DialogContext dc = await _dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        //    var data = dc.ActiveDialog?.State.Values;
        //    if (data != null)
        //    {
        //        await LogTranscriptFromQnAAnswer(turnContext, data);
        //    }
        //}

        protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            //turnContext.Activity.Text = MaskData(turnContext.Activity.Text);
            await TranscriptStore.LogActivityAsync(turnContext.Activity);

            // Get the state properties from the turn context.
            MessageRouter.StoreConversationReferences(turnContext.Activity);
            AbstractMessageRouterResult messageRouterResult = null;

            bool.TryParse(
                    Configuration[KeyRejectConnectionRequestIfNoAggregationChannel],
                    out bool rejectConnectionRequestIfNoAggregationChannel);

            var conversationStateAccessors = ConversationState.CreateProperty<ConversationData>(nameof(ConversationData));
            var conversationData = await conversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ConversationData());

            var userStateAccessors = UserState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
            var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userProfile.Id))
            {
                // First time around this is set to false, so we will prompt user for name.
                if (conversationData.PromptedUserForId)
                {
                  
                    userProfile.Id = turnContext.Activity.Text?.Trim();
                    var thanksMsg = $"Thank you";
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(thanksMsg);

                    IActivity activityFromBot = BuildActivity(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Bot", turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id, thanksMsg);
                    await TranscriptStore.LogActivityAsync(activityFromBot);

                    turnContext.Activity.Text = "Hello";
                    // Reset the flag to allow the bot to go through the cycle again.
                    conversationData.PromptedUserForId = false;
                    //}
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    await PromptForUserId(turnContext);
                    // Set the flag to true, so we don't prompt in the next turn.
                    conversationData.PromptedUserForId = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if (turnContext.Activity.Text.Equals("Save Transcript", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                StringBuilder transcriptContents = await GetTranscriptContents(turnContext, userProfile);

                byte[] bytes = StringToBytes(transcriptContents.ToString());

                var contentType = "text/plain";
                var attachment = new Attachment
                {
                    Name = $"Transcript_{userProfile.Name}.txt",
                    ContentUrl = $"data:{contentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)}",
                    ContentType = contentType
                };

                var activity = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachment);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity);
                return;
            }

            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(turnContext.Activity.Text)
                            && (turnContext.Activity.Text.ToLower().Contains("human") || turnContext.Activity.Text.ToLower().Contains("agent")))
            {
                // Let the message router route the activity, if the sender is connected with another user/bot
                messageRouterResult = await MessageRouter.RouteMessageIfSenderIsConnectedAsync(turnContext.Activity);

                if (messageRouterResult is MessageRoutingResult
                       && (messageRouterResult as MessageRoutingResult).Type == MessageRoutingResultType.NoActionTaken)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"You have requested transfer to an agent, ConversationId={turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id}");
                    IActivity activity = turnContext.Activity;

                    if (activity.Type is ActivityTypes.Message)
                    {

                        if (await CommandHandler.HandleCommandAsync(turnContext) == false)
                        {
                            messageRouterResult = MessageRouter.CreateConnectionRequest(
                         MessageRouter.CreateSenderConversationReference(activity),
                         rejectConnectionRequestIfNoAggregationChannel);
                        }
                    }
                  


                }
                // Handle the result, if necessary
                await MessageRouterResultHandler.HandleResultAsync(messageRouterResult);
                return;
            }

            // Add message details to the conversation data.
            // Convert saved Timestamp to local DateTimeOffset, then to string for display.
            var messageTimeOffset = (DateTimeOffset)turnContext.Activity.Timestamp;
            var localMessageTime = messageTimeOffset.ToLocalTime();
            conversationData.Timestamp = localMessageTime.ToString();
            conversationData.ChannelId = turnContext.Activity.ChannelId.ToString();

            // Run the Dialog with the new message Activity.
            await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
            var dialodAccesser = ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState));
            var dialog = await dialodAccesser.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new DialogState());
            var _dialogSet = new DialogSet(dialodAccesser);
            DialogContext dc = await _dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            var data = dc.ActiveDialog?.State.Values;
            if (data != null)
            {
                await LogTranscriptFromQnAAnswer(turnContext, data);
            }
        }


        private async Task<StringBuilder> GetTranscriptContents(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, UserProfile userProfile)
        {
            var transcripts = await TranscriptStore.GetTranscriptActivitiesAsync(turnContext.Activity.ChannelId, turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id);
            var transcriptContents = new StringBuilder();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userProfile.Id))
            {
                transcriptContents.Append("UserId : " + userProfile.Id);
            }

            foreach (var transcript in transcripts)
            {
                transcriptContents.AppendLine(transcript.document.From + "\t:\t" + transcript.document.Text);
            }

            return transcriptContents;
        }

        private async Task LogTranscriptFromQnAAnswer(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, ICollection<object> data)
        {
            foreach (DialogState kv in data)
            {
                var ds = kv.DialogStack;
                var qnaData = ds[0].State;
                foreach (var kvPaires in qnaData)
                {
                    if (kvPaires.Key.Equals("values"))
                    {
                        var qna = (Dictionary<string, object>)kvPaires.Value;

                        foreach (var q in qna)
                        {
                            if (q.Key.Equals("qnaData"))
                            {
                                var ans = (List<QueryResult>)q.Value;
                                var queryResult = ans[0];

                                QueryResult qResult = new QueryResult
                                {
                                    Answer = ans[0].Answer
                                };

                                IActivity activity = BuildActivity(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Bot", turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id, ans[0].Answer);
                                await TranscriptStore.LogActivityAsync(activity);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task PromptForUserId(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext)
        {
            // Prompt the user for their id.
            var verificationMsg = $"For verification purpose can you please type your User ID";
            IActivity activityFromBot = BuildActivity(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Bot", turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id, verificationMsg);

            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activityFromBot);
            await TranscriptStore.LogActivityAsync(activityFromBot);
        }

        protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    var welcomeText = $"NCI Welcomes You..! Please type in Hello and press ENTER to chat with us. Please do not share any Personally Identifiable Information during the course of this chat.";
                    IActivity activityFromBot = BuildActivity(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Bot", turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id, welcomeText);
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activityFromBot, cancellationToken);
                    await TranscriptStore.LogActivityAsync(activityFromBot);
                }
            }
        }

        private byte[] StringToBytes(string transcriptToSend)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[transcriptToSend.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(transcriptToSend.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }

        private IActivity BuildActivity(string activityId, string from, string conversationId, string text)
        {
            return new Activity
            {
                Id = activityId,
                From = new ChannelAccount
                {
                    Name = from
                },
                Conversation = new ConversationAccount
                {
                    Id = conversationId
                },
                Text = text,
                Type = ActivityTypes.Message
            };
        }

        private User AuthenticateUser(string userId)
        {
            //TODO AS400 User verificaion implemetation should go here
            return new User
            {
                Id = userId,
                firstName = "Johny",
                lastName = "Depp"
            };
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm facing difficults with handoff library too. From what I can tell you, (at this moment) it's a 'draft' library, and it requires accounts on 3rd party services for the agent hub. You'd better implement your own, of if you can, go with the 3rd party agent hubs

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I have implemented  agent functionality in individually project but can't figure it out how it will be merged here

Comment: just like how you have the controller which maps to /api/messages, you'll need another one to receive messages from agent. Then, you need to keep the conversation Id to avoid the bot to reply. Unfortunately, there's no magic, you'll endup implementing your own "chat" and use the bot framework just as the starting point

Comment: What specific errors are you running into when you try your implementation that you have so far? Additionally, have you looked at the experimental samples of the handoff library in the [botbuilder-samples repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples)?

Comment: @Zeryth I already seen this example.

Comment: @NegiRox you still have not detailed any particular error you are facing. Additionally, instead of implementing a QnAMaker bot then converting it to do handoff, it would be easier to start with a trying to get a working bas of a handoff bot, then converting it to support QnA Maker. An example is, I have successfully implemented [DynamicsOmniChannelBot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples/DynamicsOmnichannelBot), and I could just easily add a condition "if result == QueryResult" or along those lines to support QnA

Comment: @Zeryth I also implemented this. now challenge is something new like one to many communication.

Comment: @Zeryth above solution will only send a request nothing else i want once user want to escalate request should go to agent and agent will be able to communicate. I implemented what i explained but now challenge is one to many communication